# PageFile Question

Tags: pagefile

On a Windows 2003 Server - we have a page file of 1GB at the moment. I don't really know a lot about pagefiles, what is the minimum size, what are they used for? How small can I make it?

The system it is running on is running out of space and there aren't many other places that I can get much more free space from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any question relating to setting page files can be answered by [referring to this answer to another (similar) question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/23621/any-benefit-or-detriment-from-removing-a-pagefile-on-an-8gb-ram-machine/23684#23684).

The short answer is: Just let Windows manage it. It knows what it's doing.

If your server is running out of space and there's nothing you can delete, then it's very possible (and likely) that it's time to look into alternatives, because even if you did manage to remove a 1gb page file, that's still only 1gb of extra space. Unless you're on a 4gb drive, this will negate any benefits you might gain.

(By alternatives I mean bigger/more disks, migrating to a new server)

Answer (score 0):

You could run without a pagefile, but I wouldn't recommend it as the server would most definitely have issues. Try setting the min and max to the amount of RAM in the server.