# How to reduce page file usage on windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Is there a way that we can reduce the Page File usage?

Comment: Related: have a look at this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/23621/any-benefit-or-detriment-from-removing-a-pagefile-on-an-8gb-ram-machine/23684#23684

Comment: Is the question that you want to reduce page file usage(eg. because you are running on flash) or actually that you want to reduce excessive swapping?

Answer (score 3):

Windows has a page file not a swap file.  Every commited memory page will be backed by page file (if sufficient page file exists).  You should notice that commited memory is alomst exactly equal to page file usage.  You should not try to optimize windows to not use the page file. See [How to tell if my windows server is swapping](https://serverfault.com/questions/74822/how-do-i-tell-if-my-windows-server-is-swapping/75027#75027) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Install more RAM
2. Run less stuff on the server

Comment: installling more ram will not stop pages from committing to disk

Comment: At least in Windows XP, I can set a 32 MB page file, and as long as I'm not over-committing physical memory, that page file doesn't grow. So, I'm guessing that it will, if 2003 handles memory the same way.